# Gatt server does not catch connection signals

Tags: python, bluez

I am working with the sample gatt server provided with BlueZ and have added a signal handler to detect connections and disconnections like so:

```
bus.add_signal_receiver(PropertiesChangedHandler,                      
                    dbus_interface = "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",                          
                    signal_name = "PropertiesChanged",                                           
                    arg0 = "org.bluez.Device1",                                                  
                    path_keyword = "path")
```

My signal handler simply prints out some information:

```
def PropertiesChangedHandler(interface, changed, invalidated, path):       
    if 'Connected' in changed:                                             
        print("---- Connected Property Changed ----")                      
        print('Interface: ', interface)                                                              
        print('Changed: ', changed['Connected'])                                                     
        print('Path: ', path)                                                                        
    if 'ServicesResolved' in changed:                                                                
        print("---- ServicesResolved Property Changed ----")                                         
        print('Interface: ', interface)                                                              
        print('Changed: ', changed['ServicesResolved'])                                              
        print('Path: ', path)
```

When running the server, however, I am only able to detect disconnections. I never get any signals for connections. I added 'ServicesResolved' to the signals being handled and it seemed to work as expected. My logs look a like this when I connect and disconnect:

---- ServicesResolved Property Changed ----
Interface:  org.bluez.Device1
Changed:  1
Path:  /org/bluez/hci0/dev_42_36_D9_11_CA_4B
---- Connected Property Changed ----
Interface:  org.bluez.Device1
Changed:  0
Path:  /org/bluez/hci0/dev_42_36_D9_11_CA_4B
---- ServicesResolved Property Changed ----
Interface:  org.bluez.Device1
Changed:  0
Path:  /org/bluez/hci0/dev_42_36_D9_11_CA_4B

What reason(s) could there be for this strange behavior? I am using BlueZ 5.46 if that matters.

Comment: Bluez 4.46? It's already deprecated!

Comment: @Parthiban my apologies that was a typo on my part. I am actually on 5.46. Edited the question to reflect the correct info.